# Android, Can I share my updated SDK with other programmers?

Tags: android, sdk, download

In my country accessing to android website in order to download the SDK is denied. There are several programmers that can't download SDK. I'm not in my country, so I can download and update SDK.

My question is, can they use my SDK if I compress (zip) that folder and share it for them?

Comment: Well, it's not kind question. Yes you can do that. But users from denied country wont be able to again update the SDK from their computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can save it to a central, network directory where anyone can link to it by his/her own.

The current state of a SDK directory can be stored in a ZIP file and be copied and extracted to another person.